# Creating Static resource from JS in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am having a VF page with some JS part coded in it, now I want to make that JS part as static resource, what I did is, created a js file from the js part and upload it to static resource. But Iam not getting the desired  functionality since I am not able to get alerts. Can any one help me out in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include link to this Static resource in your Visualforce page. Try to add

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.NAME_OF_YOUR_STATIC_RESOURCE}"/>
```

in your page.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have one more doubt do we get alert which are present in static resources ?.

Comment: yes, all JS code which is included from Static resource will work like it have been added directly in page.